# Is it possible to dynamically activate a package in Flutter? (According to web build, mobile build)

Tags: flutter, web, mobile, import

Currently, i am developing mobile and web applications with flutter.
As shown in the figure below, the index.html of the web folder is not used on mobile but used when running on the web.

[image]

And in the code I would like to use'KIsWeb' as below to use addSearch.dart as mobile view and addSearchWeb.dart as web view.

[image]

However, when running on mobile, the index.html file cannot be read and an error occurs as follows (using the js package).

Currently
import'package: flutter_app2/addSearch.dart';
import'package: flutter_app2/addSearchWeb.dart';
There are two references.

Can I only use import'package:flutter_app2/addSearch.dart' when running on mobile, and use only import'package:flutter_app2/addSearchWeb.dart' when running on the web?

(like a Using the if function

```
if(kIsWeb) import 'package:flutter_app2/addSearch.dart';
else import 'package:flutter_app2/addSearch.dart';
```

)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Technically you can't activate imports dynamically.
But, you can import packages with alias first like this:

```
import 'package:flutter_app2/addSearch.dart' as as1;
import 'package:flutter_app2/addSearch.dart' as as2;
```

and then in your related class, you can use these two imports dynamically like this:

```
class ClassName{
   var a = as1.something;
   var b = as2.something;

   someMethod(){
      var x = kIsWeb? a : b;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using something like this:

```
import 'package: flutter_app2/addSearch.dart'
    if (dart.library.html) 'package: flutter_app2/addSearchWeb.dart';
```

Remember to create the same class/method structure for both `addSearch.dart` and `addSearchWeb.dart`